# How to cover the metal showing in recessed lighting?

Tags: lighting, recessed-lighting

I have just installed new recessed lighting in my basement with exposed ceiling. That was the easy part. I happen to have a **lot** of traditional styled LED light-bulbs that I'd like to put in them. My problem is using these light bulbs, you can see bare metal when standing underneath them. Is there a good product or technique to cover the metal and make it look more finished?

[image: Recessed Light]

Comment: Choice of the right fixture, or choice of the right bulb shape for the fixture you chose are the usual methods you have evidently opted to avoid.

Comment: I will admit that I probably should have done a bit more research, but home improvement stores do not let you compare your options easily. I may have to buy the correct bulbs. I was hoping that there was another option is all.

Comment: Most home improvement stores have quite liberal return policies, in my experience. Of course if you've mounted all the fixtures rather than taking one out of the box and putting a bulb in it and going "hmm" that may not be an option you wish to use.

Comment: The easiest/cheapest/best-aesthetic way to fix this is to just go buy the correct bulbs.

Answer (score -1):

You could cover the bare metal with paint. If you paint it the same color as the baffle (white), it should be less noticeable.